# How do I create a Linux bootup USB stick that only runs my one program automatically?

Tags: linux, usb, boot

I want to create a USB stick that has the smallest version of Linux possible that only runs my one program automatically when booted from.

Do I have to write my program in a special way to do this?

Do I have to build the Linux kernel myself in order to be able to distribute the software without having to pay anyone else?

Thanks!

Comment: What is that "one program"? If it is not anything graphical, you can just install a boot loader (syslinux / GRUB), include a kernel and an initramfs with your single program (`/init`) (statically-compiled, otherwise you need to include libraries too).

Answer (score 0):

Universal USB Installer  does it for you.

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

You can install archlinux on it which is very light. And then you can write a script to execute your program on start up.

It will all be free, but for commercial use, read the GNU license that comes with the linux distributions.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for this
http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/wiki/installing_to_a_usb_flash_drive.html